# How to automate post install setup

Tags: automation, cyanogenmod, scripts

I've noticed recently that i spend quite a bit of time setting up various settings after a clean ROM install. I was wondering how could i automate this post install hassle.

Specificly im talking about CyanogenMod 11-M9 and Android 4.4.4.

I know the settings are stored somewhere when i change system settings but im not sure where exactly. And what are the possible solutions?

If the settings are stored in human-readabale text files then maybe it's possible to create update.zip that i can flash in recovery and that updates the nessesary files with my settings?
Or perhaps there is a way to create a script that i can run post install when i have set up preliminary things?

Or maybe i should just build my own ROM from sources that already includes my customized setting (tho this is problably too complex at first).

To clarify - im talking about system settings starting from setting up google account and ending in custom alarms. 3rd party app settings i can restore easily with Titanium Backup but it doesent seem TB is able to restore system settings (possibly because system is running at the time?).

I would be greateful for any tips on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I have yet to find anything like this myself. I can only envision doing something with the computer and something like ADB. But even then if you have incompatible "Settings" apps between ROMs or anything like that it would break. The whole setup could be very brittle as a result. I'll have a look into it, and I'll see if there are scripts about, but as it stands most ROM users are doing the Google Account / Titanium Backup dance each time. Unless, of course, you use a ROM not requiring a full wipe! E.g. Wanam Lite ROM.

Comment: 'Or maybe i should just build my own ROM from sources that already includes my customized setting' This sounds prohibitively difficult for so little pay off. One thing you might consider if you're serious about this question is learning `shell` or `bash`, which isn't too difficult IMHO, and then create a script to automatically backup then propagate your settings. This may or may not work depending if they've changed the settings file between distros. Using a shell or python script is how I quickly propagate settings when setting up duplicate test servers at work.